# Fastest command to create a bit identical copy of a 4GB USB 2.0 drive

Tags: usb, 16.04, backup, dd, copy

I have tried `dd if=path_to_usb_drive of=path_to_copy_to`, but it's too slow.  How can this be speeded up?

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can [increase the block size](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd):

```
bs=BYTES
       read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time
```

For example:

```
dd if=path_to_usb_drive of=path_to_copy_to bs=8192
```